# Double sided DVD's: Is it possible to have a dual-layer (both sided) DVD that is usable for 9.4GB Distro Installs?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, dvd, ubiquity

I was looking at installs with all my OSS software, and the 4.7GB limit was reached for install of a particular Linux distro.

My question is is it possible to have a [Double-sided](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0006TNA2K) DVD-RAM (i.e. the ones you see for PC game installations), and use bothy sides in the full 9.4GB Linux Distro install ?

What, for example, would be the running-off-disc problems that you'd encounter when ejecting one side of the disc, in terms of ubiquity/or similar, and then re-insert the other side (B) of the 9.4 GB DVD-RAM disc ?

Would the installer application allow for this ? Or would it need a disc constantly spinning in the DVD-drive for a full install ?

Just want to know it this is feasible-for-full-install or not, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Each side of the disk will act like a separate disk, so if the installer supports multiple disks it will work with a double-sided disk (assuming the contents of both sides are prepared appropriately). For example, the [Debian installer](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s03.html#di-install-software) supports multiple CDs or DVDs and would be usable with a double-sided DVD.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot as the double sided media does not offer a single data space.

You have to flip the medium and remount it to get the other side and thus cannot copy a 9GB install medium to such a disk.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to configure the install media to grab files from multiple local sources. As far as I know this is not possible, or else somebody would have done something similar but for multiple CDs. Instead, all I find when looking at installing from a CD refer to downloading the extra packages from the internet. It seems impossible to utilize more than one local source in Ubuntu's installer at least.

Even if you managed to utilize ore than one local source, you would have to deal with the fact that the first side with the OS files becomes inaccessible once you flip to the other side of the disc. All OS files would need to be put into a RAMdisk.

You may wish to purchase a Blu-Ray drive or use a flash drive instead.